# Flutter: How to destroy http queue request?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm currently using [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) flutter package. I would like to know is there any method to destroy all ongoing http api request from server ?

Example:
Before moving to **pageB** from **pageA**, I need to destroy all the request from **pageA**.
When I'm inside **pageB** it will only call **pageB** api request.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you looking for :

[image]

Comment: Can we make client as a global variable and use client.close to destroy all the request ? For example I have 5 client I need to client.close 5 times ?

Comment: Yes you can make it as global variable. 
Like the document said, you must make sure to close the client when the request is done. So basically you will close every client that you make 5 client and you will close it when it done.

Comment: What if the 5 client not yet done and I instantly go to new page. Will it client.close 5 times too ?

Comment: You can call `close()` first before move to new page. Have you tried it though ?

Comment: trying now will let you know soon